# Equivalence of these three statements about convergence of events in a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, limits, convergence-divergence

Could you explain to me why these three statements are equivalent. Everything takes place in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$. Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of events in $\mathcal A$. $1_A$ denotes the indicator function on $A$.

1. $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n=\liminf_{n\to \infty} A_n=A$$
2. $$\lim_{n\to \infty} 1_{A_n}=1_A$$
3. $\{A_n\}$ converges to $A$

Comment: What is here the definition of '$(A_n)_n$ converges to $A$'? Is it not some 'restatement' of 2)?

Comment: Do I use that as a definition and try to prove (1)?

Comment: If you prove that 2) implies 1) then in my view you are ready if you combine it with the solution that I gave you in my answer. This because 3) and 2) are (again in my view) essentially the same statements. For certainty you could have a look at the definition that is given unto you of: '$A_n$ converges to $A$'.

Comment: I made that up (was reading a book and thought that's how it should be defined). I'll take (2) as a definition for (3).

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution:

Suppose that 1) is true.

If $1_{A}\left(x\right)=1$ or equivalently
$x\in A=\liminf A_{n}$ wich means that some $n$ exists
with $k\geq n\Rightarrow x\in A_{k}$ or equivalently $1_{A_{k}}\left(x\right)=1$
for each $k\geq n$.

That allows the conclusion that $\lim1_{A_{n}}\left(x\right)=1$.

If $1_{A}\left(x\right)=0$ or equivalently $x\notin A=\limsup A_{n}$
wich means that some $n$ exists with $k\geq n\Rightarrow x\notin A_{k}$
or equivalently $1_{A_{k}}\left(x\right)=0$ for each $k\geq n$.

That allows the conclusion that $\lim1_{A_{n}}\left(x\right)=0$.

In both cases we found that $\lim1_{A_{n}}\left(x\right)=1_{A}\left(x\right)$, so statement 2) is true.